# Prefix labels of a categorical column with numbers based on an order

Tags: r

Consider a data frame with two numeric columns (`x`, `y`) and a categorical column (`category`) containing a string:

```r
d1 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 5, 6.5, 8), y = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 5.5, 5), category = "A")
d2 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8), y = c(0, 3, 3.5, 4, 4, 5), category = "B")
d3 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1.5, 3, 4, 6.5, 8), y = c(0, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5, 5), category = "C")
df <- rbind(d1, d2, d3)
```

```r
> df
     x   y category
1  0.0 0.0        A
2  1.0 2.0        A
3  2.0 3.0        A
4  5.0 5.0        A
5  6.5 5.5        A
6  8.0 5.0        A
7  0.0 0.0        B
8  1.0 3.0        B
9  2.0 3.5        B
10 4.0 4.0        B
11 6.0 4.0        B
12 8.0 5.0        B
13 0.0 0.0        C
14 1.5 2.5        C
15 3.0 3.0        C
16 4.0 4.0        C
17 6.5 4.5        C
18 8.0 5.0        C
```

Based on the order of the sum of the last 3 `y` values for each distinct `category` value, I would like to append a number plus a dot as a prefix to the values of the category column. For the above example, those sums in ascending order would be `13`, `13.5` and `15.5` for `B`, `C` and `A` respectively. The number to be prefixed to the categorical column values should correspondingly represent this order in accordance with the `category` label, i.e. `1.B`, `2.C`, `3.A` should be the renamed values in `category` for the former `B`, `C` and `A` respectively. My desired output is shown below:

```r
     x   y category
1  0.0 0.0      3.A
2  1.0 2.0      3.A
3  2.0 3.0      3.A
4  5.0 5.0      3.A
5  6.5 5.5      3.A
6  8.0 5.0      3.A
7  0.0 0.0      1.B
8  1.0 3.0      1.B
9  2.0 3.5      1.B
10 4.0 4.0      1.B
11 6.0 4.0      1.B
12 8.0 5.0      1.B
13 0.0 0.0      2.C
14 1.5 2.5      2.C
15 3.0 3.0      2.C
16 4.0 4.0      2.C
17 6.5 4.5      2.C
18 8.0 5.0      2.C
```

I'm able to collect the ordered sum values with corresponding `category` values in a list, but am unable to think past this:

```r
endsum <- list()
diff <- unique(df$category)
for(i in 1:length(diff)) {
  endsum[diff[i]] <- sum(tail(subset(df, category == diff[i])$y, 3))
}
endsum <- endsum[order(sapply(endsum, function(a) a))]
```

```r
> endsum
$B
[1] 13

$C
[1] 13.5

$A
[1] 15.5
```

I did think of comparing `names(endsum)[i]` with `df$category` while traversing `df` row-wise and for matches, append the number maintained in the list order along with a dot, i.e. for e.g. when `B` from `names(endsum)[1]` gets matched with the data frame's category label `B`, or rows 7-12 of `df`, it will take its order in the list `i` which is 1, and prefix it (with a dot) to rows 7-12 of `df`, turning the `B` into `1.B`.

However, am unsure of its implementation and this does not seem to be the best approach. Could anyone suggest a better way to achieve this? Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each group keep the last 3 rows and `sum` their `y` values, `arrange` the data based on the sum and paste the row number to the `category` column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 3) %>%
  summarise(y = sum(y)) %>%
  arrange(y) %>%
  mutate(new_category = paste(row_number(), category, sep = '.')) %>%
  select(-y) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'category')

#  category new_category     x     y
#   <chr>    <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 B        1.B            0     0  
# 2 B        1.B            1     3  
# 3 B        1.B            2     3.5
# 4 B        1.B            4     4  
# 5 B        1.B            6     4  
# 6 B        1.B            8     5  
# 7 C        2.C            0     0  
# 8 C        2.C            1.5   2.5
# 9 C        2.C            3     3  
#10 C        2.C            4     4  
#11 C        2.C            6.5   4.5
#12 C        2.C            8     5  
#13 A        3.A            0     0  
#14 A        3.A            1     2  
#15 A        3.A            2     3  
#16 A        3.A            5     5  
#17 A        3.A            6.5   5.5
#18 A        3.A            8     5
```

Probably this one is shorter with the same logic :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(sum_y = sum(tail(y, 3))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(sum_y) %>%
  mutate(category = paste(match(category, unique(category)),category, sep = '.'))
```

---

In base R this can be written as :

```
df1 <- aggregate(y~category, df, function(x) sum(tail(x, 3)))
df1 <- df1[order(df1$y), -2, drop = FALSE]
df1$new_category <- paste(seq(nrow(df1)), df1$category, sep = '.')
merge(df1, df, by = 'category')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, very elegant! just curious - is this achievable without `dplyr` (trying to reduce dependencies) in a similar manner?

Comment: Updated the answer to include a base R option.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner base R solution.  Since there is no `ties.method = "dense"` in `rank()` in r, I first converted it to factor and then `as.integer` to return the dense ranks.

```
df$category <- paste(as.integer(factor(rank(ave(df$y, df$category, FUN = function(x){n <- length(x); sum(x[(n-2):n])}), 
     ties.method = "min"))), df$category, sep = ".")

df
     x   y category
1  0.0 0.0      3.A
2  1.0 2.0      3.A
3  2.0 3.0      3.A
4  5.0 5.0      3.A
5  6.5 5.5      3.A
6  8.0 5.0      3.A
7  0.0 0.0      1.B
8  1.0 3.0      1.B
9  2.0 3.5      1.B
10 4.0 4.0      1.B
11 6.0 4.0      1.B
12 8.0 5.0      1.B
13 0.0 0.0      2.C
14 1.5 2.5      2.C
15 3.0 3.0      2.C
16 4.0 4.0      2.C
17 6.5 4.5      2.C
18 8.0 5.0      2.C
```

Answer (score 0):

Another soluntion using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

# Create sum of last 3 rows and rank the sum
last3 <- dt[, .SD[c(.N-2, .N-1, .N)], by="category"]
order <- last3[ , .(endsum=sum(y)), by="category"][ , rank := rank(endsum)]

# Merge rank to dt and create prefix
dt_final <- merge(dt, order, by="category")
dt_final[ , category := paste0(rank, ".", category)]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an approach using `data.table`, fits well! +1